# Table with black outer, but grey inner border

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

I want to create a html table with a 1pt black outer border and the same border around every td.

Should look like this (only the borders, of course)

[image]

I use

```
<table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse; border-color:Black; border-style:solid; border-width:1pt">
```

As a result I get a black outer, but grey inner borders.

Comment: What browser are you testing on? Your code produces black (or whatever is specified) inner borders on Chrome.

Comment: ah thanks, very interesting! I use Internet Explorer.

Comment: It's not super clear from your question whether you *wanted* the grey inner border (as the title suggests) or if that's the problem, and you want black borders throughout. If you want black borders throughout, all you have to do is move your CSS border declarations from the `table` selector to the `td` selector.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try implement something like this in your CSS stylesheet.

```
.mytable
{
border-collapse:collapse; 
border-color:#000000; 
border-style:solid; 
border-width:2px;
}

.mytable td
{
border-color:#cccccc; /*grey*/
border-style:solid; 
border-width:1px;
}
```

And something like this HTML:

```
<table class="mytable">
    <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/3wjTT/)

Comment: The css selector should be table.mytable - without space - or just .mytable. Like it is now you are targeting a .mytable class inside a table.

Comment: Great! I thought it would work without speaking to the td´s,
but that seems not to be so.

Comment: Your example conveniently has a thicker outer border on the table, which is the only reason it takes priority over the inner `td` borders. That should be mentioned in your answer. Having said that, the OP actually said he wanted 'the same border around every td'. I suspect he wanted black, 1px borders throughout (not grey on the inside), which is a much simpler problem of course. The question could really be worded more clearly.